# Is a variety always contained in a hypersurface of smaller or equal degree?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, hypersurfaces

(a) Let $V\subset \mathbb{A}^n$ be an affine variety (not necessarily irreducible). Write $\deg(V)$ for the sum of the degrees of its irreducible components. Must there be a hypersurface $W\subset \mathbb{A}^n$ with $\deg(W)\leq \deg(V)$ containing $V$?

(b) Let $V,Z\subset \mathbb{A}^n$ be affine varieties such that $V$ does not contain $Z$. Must there be a hypersurface $W\subset \mathbb{A}^n$ with $\deg(W)\leq \deg(V)$ containing $V$ but not $Z$?

(Note: in both cases, I am talking about affine varieties over arbitrary fields.)

Comment: Over an infinite field this can be proven by generic projection to a hypersurface.

Comment: @Mohan Aha - how?

Comment: First, clearly you may assume $V$ is irreducible of dimension, say $d$. Then for a generic projection to $\mathbb{A}^{d+1}$, the image is a hypersurface of degree same as $\deg V$. This gives what you want.

Comment: Can one assume right away that $V$ is irreducible? Notice the condition that $W$ contain $V$. Won't you end up with a $W$ that just contains one of the components of $V$?

Comment: I agree the above works for $V$ irreducible (and it can presumably be made to work for $V$ pure-dimensional as well).

Comment: If the Hilbert polynomial gave the right dimensions (for all n) for the linear spaces of elements of I(V) of given degree n (this is in fact true for n large enough), we would have a proof that works for V pure-dimensional: if a non-zero polynomial vanishes on 0,1,2,...,m-1, then it has degree at least m; hence, if I(V) contains no polynomials of degree <m, V must have degree at least m.

Comment: Your definition of "degree" is not standard. Usually $\deg(V)$ is the sum of the degrees of the maximum dimensional irreducible components. In your question, you are also adding the degree of smaller dimensional components. That should make it easier to give a positive answer to question (1): for each component $V_i$ of $V$, there's a hypersurface $W_i$ containing it with degree less than $\deg(V_i)$, as @Mohan explained. Then $W$ can be the union of the $W_i$.

Comment: @ZachTeilter Right, if one allows a hypersurface to be reducible, all is well. That's actually fine for the application I have in mind, but now I wonder what the answer is if one requires hypersurfaces to be reducible.

Comment: I think @Mohan's answer can be adapted to (b) as well (in that, if we consider a variety V of codimension >1 and a single point P outside it, a generic line through P will not intersect V - and so, for $\pi$ a generic projection, $\pi(V)$ will not contain $\pi(P)$. Iterate.

Comment: @ZachTeitler I know it's not quite standard (that's why I gave the definition). It's a convenient way to pack relevant information, however - it behaves well under intersections, by Fulton-Macpherson's generalized Bézout theorem.

Comment: Ah, obviously one can't require the hypersurface to be irreducible - that's impossible if $V$ is a reducible hypersurface to begin with!

Comment: PS. I'm happy to pass to let $W$ be defined over the algebraic closure, so @MohanAha's solution works.